# Omniscience of Jesus

Tags: matthew, christology

Was Jesus omniscient when he said "But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but the Father alone?" (Mathew 24:36 NASB 1995)

This question examines whether Jesus was all knowing in his humanity,
while at the same time not knowing the exact time of his return.

Comment: Why do you think he needed to be all-knowing in order to make that one statement?
I could truthfully say that "*No one knows when the alarm clock will ring, except for my wife who set it.*", but there is no implication there that *I* am omniscient.

Comment: @Stevie C. This has already been asked "How to reconcile Matthew 24:36 with Revelation 22:12a?" and I think its six answers probably cover everything you are asking about.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth, If Jesus was not all-knowing then that would beg the question... When Jesus grew in wisdom and in stature (Luke 2:52), was he learning from the process of trial and error?

Comment: @StevieC., not all denominations will agree with this, but when Jesus became human, he totally gave up his divinity. [Philippians 2 (NLT)](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nlt/phl/2/7-8/s_1105007) says "*… he gave up his divine privileges … and was born as a human being.*".  The incarnate Jesus was fully human, with no supernatural power. Everything he did was as a human with the assistance of God's holy spirit, the same holy spirit that fully converted Christians possess.  The only difference was that, unlike other humans, his faith was perfect from the beginning.

Comment: @RayButterworth. If "he gave up his divine privileges … and was born as a human being", then he is not God, correct? What divine privileges did Jesus  gave up in Philippians 2?

Comment: @RayButterworth *he totally gave up his divinity* What do you base this on *apart from* some serious reading-in to Phil 2 You are making up your own definition of 'emptying himself' - which refers to him having a servant attitude instead of an over lording attitude he was entitled to. HOW does God stop being God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo, except for retaining God's perfect character, he gave up *everything*. Consider John 3:16 (*For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son*) and ask what was actually involved here. Had Jesus retained any divinity, retained his immortality, what was the big deal? He lives, he dies, he's resurrected. That's not giving or sacrificing. It's only when we realize that Jesus the man *could have died* that we begin to understand how greatly "God loved the world". As fully human, had he sinned, Jesus would have earned permanent death; there would have been no resurrection.

Comment: @RayButterworth. Does John 3:16 say God gave Himself/everything? Can God die? say for 3 days?

Comment: @AlexBalilo, if surrendering his divinity and risking permanent death wasn't Jesus's sacrifice, what was? How did God "so love the world" if no risk was involved? Was the temptation in the desert just a game? If Jesus wasn't risking his immortal life, what was the point of the whole exercise, simply to "slum it" with the mortals? ¶ Adam was the type for Jesus. Each had a choice between immortal life and eternal death. Adam chose wrong; Jesus demonstrated that it was possible for a human to make the right choice.

Comment: @RayButterworth. Does the risk justify making God mortal?

Comment: @AlexBalilo asks "*Does the risk justify making God mortal?*".  The Father and the Son obviously thought so.

Comment: @RayButterworth. commented "Does the risk justify making God mortal?". The Father and the Son obviously thought so.".has no biblical support.

Comment: @RayButterworth, if Jesus was aware that he is the Son of God, then he does not risk a thing. But I am very concerned about the unfalsifiable fallacy that this argument presents. I mean, any man who we do not know who was his father, can claim that he is 100% God but he gave up on his divinity. And such  claim would indeed lead him eventually to execution. And doing miracles does not help, because through witchcrafting you could do many things that appears like miracles

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost the same as asking about Mark 2:8 and whether it should read:

> And immediately, Jesus having known in His spirit that ...

or

> And immediately, Jesus having known by His Spirit [ie, the Holy
> Spirit] that ...

The first implies omniscience and the second implies dependence on the enlightenment of the Holy Spirit for humanly inaccessible information. [Spoiler alert: I am inclined to the latter view for reasons to be explained shortly.]

Whatever, Matt 24:36 teaches, it shows that Jesus, at least during His incarnation was NOT omniscient.  Indeed, as many have correctly pointed out, Jesus appeared to be anything but divine:

- He appeared to be very human, John 1:14, 8:40, 10:33, 1 John 4:2, 2 John 7
- He was subject to death and thus not immortal, John 19:17-42
- He was not omniscient, Matt 24:36
- He was not omnipresent but existed in a single location at any time.
- He was born of a woman, Gal 4:4, Heb 2:14, 17
- He was dependent on the Father and thus was not omnipotent, John 5:19, 10:29, 14:28, Matt 26:39, etc.

All this was by the design and voluntary submission of Christ:

> Phil 2:5-8 - Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not
> consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied
> Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness.
> And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became
> obedient to death—even death on a cross.

That is, Jesus voluntarily laid aside His divine privileges to become temporarily human as Hebrews explains:

> Heb 2:8, 9, 17, 18 When God subjected all things to him, He left
> nothing outside of his control. Yet at present we do not see
> everything subject to him. **9** But we see Jesus, who was made a
> little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honor because
> He suffered death, so that by the grace of God He might taste death
> for everyone.
>
> **17** For this reason He had to be made like His brothers in every way, so that He might become a merciful and faithful high priest in
> service to God, in order to make atonement for the sins of the
> people. **18** Because He Himself suffered when He was tempted, He is
> able to help those who are being tempted.

The fact that Jesus laid aside divine powers and privileges, does not mean they were alienated from Him - that was the great temptation, far greater that we would ever experience, of having access to infinite power but voluntarily not using it.  Indeed, Jesus was still God as the Gospels observe, Matt 1:23, John 1:1, 18, 5:17, 18, 23, 8:58, 10:30, John 20:28, etc.

Comment: "Jesus was still God as the Gospels observe" You are imposing on Jesus what he refused. Philippians 2:6. John 14:28.  Granting "The fact that Jesus laid aside divine powers and privileges" how can he still retain being 100% God? Do you know if Jesus now knows that "time" now that he is in heaven?

Comment: *temporarily human as Hebrews explains:* No it does not. This is a Theological answer based on conjecture not scripture. *Jesus was still God* is simply your injected theo onto the text. The fanciful reasoning here highlights the desperate measures to make the bible align with the Creeds.

Comment: @Dottard This I cannot agree with: yes, He became fully man with all the limitations man's creaturly nature would have - fatigue, limitedness in space and time, pain, distress, hunger, thirst etc. - however, He is not two persons (one divine Logos and another human Jesus - which is Nestorianism) but one divine eternal Hypostasis of Logos, who now also has human nature. He never relinquished His divine privileges, neither could He. That's why He forgives sins, He accepts being worshiped, He works miracles, He gives His human bio-life and takes it back in a sovereign manner.

Comment: @steveowen Again: initially, from the outset, creeds are the outcome of the Scripture's interpretation, n o t the cause of Scripture interpretation. This concerns both Orthodox/Catholic and heretical creeds. Actually, first creed was made by heretics, Arians (the more sophisticated spiritual ancestors of Jehovah Witnessers) and as an answer the Orthodox/Catholic wrote their creed, the Nicene one. Thus, question is which creed is based on a better interpretation of the Scripture.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili. "Actually, first creed was made by heretics, Arians (the more sophisticated spiritual ancestors of Jehovah Witnessers) and as an answer the Orthodox/Catholic wrote their creed, the Nicene one. Thus, question is which creed is based on a better interpretation of the Scripture". So who decided which is heresy and which  is not? The people of the bible or the people of a foreign empire whose God is not the God of the bible? And how were those whom they called heretics treated?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Who decided? Holy Spirit decided through the conscientious and philologically/historically/logically sound discussion of great champions of faith, many of whom were martyrs and confessors. As to yourself, you can but study the Church history, learn arguments and conuterarguments of both Orthodox and heretics and decide for yourself who among them rings better to your conscience and why.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili. " Who decided? Holy Spirit decided through the conscientious and philologically/historically/logically sound discussion of great champions of faith, many of whom were martyrs and confessors.........." where in the bible is that?

Comment: @AlexBalilo In your glorious version of Christianity this religion started in the first century and died in the same century, while three following centuries of the Church and its great martyrs who defended faith at expense of their lives, some killed by sword, others thrown to lions, is nothing for you, because in the Bible nothing is written about them. If you, like them, will confess divinity of Christ and die for this confession, will not God account it to you as a great virtue? Or He will say: "I do not know Alex Balilo, because nothing is in Bible written about this person"?

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili. I have no glorious version of Christianity.

Answer (score -1):

**Was Jesus omniscient?**

We are not told he was. Only by reading-in presumptions from post Apostolic writings can this idea have any credence. But as we are to have a Biblical and Hermeneutic focus here, that kind of *unsanctioned* reasoning is theological in nature and should be dismissed.

Clearly Jesus is doing one of two things here.

> But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. Matt 24:36

1. Telling the truth
2. Being at least disingenuous

> He committed no sin, and no deceit was found in his mouth.  1Peter 2:22

Knowing that, and simply believing that statement as we should, we can rule out #2

Jesus was not Omniscient, he did not know the details (time) of his return - only that he would. He was not privy to know all the details of God's plan and quite explicitly we are told that he did not know this detail.

**whether Jesus was all knowing in his humanity**

Jesus, the 'last Adam' was a man and we are told nothing about him being anymore than a man - except being without sin! So as explained earlier - Jesus didn't know at any time in any way unless we read-in our own assumptions based on traditional theology.

Jesus is not the Father and even the Holy Spirit does not know - assuming of course there is a Holy Spirit separate from the one true God 'the Father' that Jesus and Paul have affirmed.

> Jesus spoke these things; and raising his eyes to heaven, he said, “Father,...3And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.

> ...there is but one God, the Father, from whom all things came... 1Cor 8:6

I concur with Dottard that, *Jesus voluntarily laid aside His divine privileges* but not the imagined *to become temporarily human*. Which again, is a theological idea without scripture to support. Much like *he totally gave up his divinity* as noted in Ray's comments.

One can only wonder why we need to impose such strange ideas onto (holy) scripture and then claim it says what is does not.

Comment: You have two downvotes but I do not see any comments.

Comment: @AlexBalilo yes that's normal. The biblical facts are not the main focus here on BH so it is regarded poorly when it highlights the peculiarities of precious doctrine.

Answer (score -1):

"As the Father knows Me, so I know the Father" (John 10:15), and how does the Father know the Son, entirely or partially? Of course entirely. That means that also the Son knows the Father entirely and exactly that's why He is the Mediator through whom we can know or "come to" the Father (John 14:6), and that's why the Father is the Mediator through whom we can know or "come to" the Son, Jesus Christ (John 6:44). The same equality of knowledge is asserted by Matthew 11:27, that nobody knows the Son save the Father and vice versa. Yes, in this divine eternal infinite reciprocal life that "predated" (if even such a time-infected word is inadequate for this eternal life) the creation of the world Both Father and the Son knew Each-Other in entirety, with no need of mediation in the manner creatures are in need of it as mentioned above.

This being established, we come to impossibility that the Lord Jesus Christ did not know such a trifle as His own Second Coming. Indeed, He knows future without any prayers for accessing this knowledge, but in a sovereign, authoritative way, saying plainly that He will be killed and rise in the third day (Luke 9:22), He knows that Judas and Peter will betray Him predicting those treasons in minute detail, He knows that Jerusalem will not accept Him and that's why it will be razed by Romans (Matthew 23:35), He knows exactly by what kind of death Peter would glorify Him (John 21:18) and also James and John (Matthew 20:22) (just consider how outlandishly stupid it is to think that He knows the future of others while being ignorant of His own future of which an aspect is His second coming and the end of history!); moreover, He knows that the limited and imperfect understanding of His words by His disciples will start to be healed by their acceptance of the Holy Spirit, whom, He predicts that Father will send to them through His intercession (John 13:7 and 14:16), and this Holy Spirit also knows the "depths of God", that is to say, the entire depth of God the Father (1 Cor. 2:10), and the Lord Jesus Christ has this Spirit in Him infinitely (John 3:34), and if so, then with all the knowledge the Spirit has, which includes the entire knowledge of the Father's depths.

If so, then how on earth could He, the Lord Jesus Christ not know such a trifle as His own second coming? Does not He separate Himself from the ignorance of the people His own knowledge of the Second Coming in Acts 1:7? And, moreover, when He promises that "I am with you until the world ends" (Matthew 28:20) does not it clearly entail that He knows that world will end and when it will end?

And the final and most important point: Second Coming is a historical event. Now, what is more principal a thing, a historical event or God's will? Which depends on which? Of course it is a plain blasphemy and idolatry to say to say that God's will depends on a historical event, for then not God is God but History - with capital letters - is real God. Now, if it is excluded and if it is God's voluntary decision when to end history, then can at all the Father will to end the history through the Second Parousia of His Son without the Latter co-willing? Impossible! It would be the same as to say that even though the Father created the world through or together with His Logos (John 1:1-3), still the Logos did not know in eternity that Father was intending to create the world: suddenly Father pinched His co-eternal Son who was eternally with Him saying: "wake up, I contrived a wonderful thing until you languished idly in your mellow drowsiness, let us create the world!" And the Son asked: "What the heck is it? Explain to Me, Dad!" "Well, the sun, the stars, mountains, Homer, Shakespeare... let us start and I will explain to you in the process, it will be wonderful!" - But it is stupid to think such mythological scenes, for the divine will and knowledge of the Father and the Son is completely identical. Thus, no historical event can ever happen without God-the-Father willing or permitting it, and He can do so only with the God-the-Son co-willing and co-permitting and co-knowing for that matter.

Thus, the Lord Jesus Christ knows, just as the Father and the Spirit know, but why does He say that "neither Son, but Father alone" (Matthew 24:37) is a separate issue, and indeed this phrase should be more correctly translated "neither the Son [would know], if not the Father [had given Him this knowledge]" - οὐδὲ ὁ υἱός, εἰ μὴ ὁ πατὴρ μόνος. But I will not dwell on this any longer, for the OP question has been already dealt with sufficiently.

Comment: @Down-voter Hey, my anonymous friend, any points that you reasonably disagree or a deficiency of English or style? If yes, would you please indicate them to me, I will be thankful, if not and you just amused yourself with givine "-", then have a good day!

Comment: " we come to impossibility that the Lord Jesus Christ did not know such a trifle as His own Second Coming" lacks proof. Does Jesus know who touched him in Luke 8:45?

Comment: @AlexBalilo If He knew under which tree Nathanael stood when this tree was not visible for any man’s physical eyes from this spot, and even knew Nathanael’s thoughts and heart saying that “ in him is no hypocrisy”, then answer yourself your own question: is it even permissible to let such a possibility as He did not know lurk in your mind?

Comment: There are things he did not know, Matthew 24:36 and Luke 8:45 show that.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Matthew 24:36 does not contradict the overwhelming evidence of His knowledge of human hearts and future events authoritatively, without prayer, like a prophet or angel would know and it can be and is well interpreted. As to Luke 8:45, by the same logic you can say that when God asked "where are you, Adam?" He was asking this out of ignorance, which is, sorry, I will not end this sentence for the words that come to the tips of my typing fingers are not nice ones.

Comment: God knew Adam sinned. The question was to make Adam confess. Not the same in the case of Luke 8:45 and Matthew 24:36.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Christ knew that this woman had immense and exemplary faith in Him and His divine ability to heal her at a touch, thus He wanted to make this exemplary faith be know to others. As simple as that! Where on earth have you discovered His ignorance?